Stored procedure that needs to get another tables data output to return
I am trying to figure out how to do this query using T-SQL that will allow me to query the table it finds the data in. Currently I have this in a stored procedure and @Temp is the temp table it puts the results in. It just shows that it found the data in table X in column X.
SELECT SchemeName, TableName, ColumnName
FROM @Temp
WHERE DataFound = 1

What I am trying to do is to take that TableName & ColumnName and do another query to pull all the data from that table back that it found that search word on.
The stored procedure looks like this:
USE [CoreDB]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC @return_value = [dbo][findMyString]
     @DataToFind = N'xml',
     @ExactMatch = 0

SELECT 'Returned Value' = @return_value

GO

I am searching for the word "XML" above. The 0 means the exact word or 1 means a wildcard %%. The output from the above looks like this:

How would one do this in a stored procedure?

Does this answer your question? How can I search all columns in a table?

@ThomA I do not think it does.

Then pelase [edit] your question to elaborate on why it doesn't. This answer, for example, has a stored procedure, and searches against a specific table, which appears to be exactly what you ask for.

I don't get it, is your original procedure searching for some value in a number of table columns and return if some value is found? And now you want it to also return the row where it found the data? This question comes up once in a while, but noone ever writes why they need this (i suspect they don't). You might wanna search previous dupes, or at least post the actual procedure

I can, if you want, at least give you a "valid" use case, @siggemannen . I recently was given "responsibility" of some databases which are awfully designed (non-meaningful object and column names (sometimes misleading), and no referential integrity), and contained no documentation. I therefore wrote a procedure that searched every table for a specific value (of a specific data type), so I could identify the table that stored the value I could see the front end, and when it finds those values, outputs those rows (along with the table schema and name).

It's not clear what you want to do with each of the results from your current procedure. Let's assume you find 2 tables as per your example. Do you want to return just the contents of the column where the data was found or (as your question suggests), the whole table? If it's the whole table how would you expect to see the results if the table structures vary? Edit your question and provide expected results. Your current proc would also be helpful as you may be able to modify that rather than wrapping something around it.

I think that showing sample data and expected result would benefit this question
